# Concatenate an infinite number of objects in java-script

Tags: javascript

My application should save each time the value from input and to concatenate the values what come from the input. There i have an ID and the name of the user which is different each time, but appear an issue in the next situation: 1. I input first name: ex: John, click on save button, and i have an result, but when i  input the second name: Ex: Jack, the previous value disappears, and i can' figure out how to `assign` an infinite number of objects what will come each time when i will click `save`. How to solve this?

```js
let res = {};
const input = (document.getElementById("input").onchange = function(e) {
  const btn = (document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
    const user = {
      name: e.target.value,
      id: 1
    };
    res = user;
    console.log(user);
  });
});

var concat = Object.assign({}, res);
console.log(concat);
```

```html
name<input type='text' id='input'/>
<button id="btn">save</button>
```

Comment: Why do you assign a click inside the change?

Comment: Assign will merge object properties by replacing, not concatenate as you expect to.

Comment: @Elias Soares, which  could be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Array and push user data to Array

```js
const concat = [];
const input = document.getElementById("input");
const btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.onclick = function() {
  const user = {
    name: input.value,
    id: +new Date()
  };
  concat.push(user);
  console.log(concat);
};
```

```html
Name : <input type='text' id='input'/>
<button id="btn">save</button>
```

Comment: All your ids are the same.

Comment: And every time the user changes the input, a new event handler is assigned to the button

Answer (score 1):

1) There's no need to have the button handler inside the input handler. As [mplungjan mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60883752/concatenate-an-infinite-number-of-objects-in-java-script/60883914#comment107717932_60883870) each time input changes a new event handler is assigned to the button. So, cache your elements, and add *one* handler to the button. It makes more sense, is more performant, and you end up with cleaner code.

2) Change `res` to an array rather than an object and you can simply [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) new objects into it.

3) You can use the length of the array to create the `id`.

```js
// Make `res` an array rather than an object
const res = [];

// Cache the elements
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const btn = document.getElementById('btn');

// Assign one handler to the button
btn.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

// When the button is clicked...
function handleClick() {

  // ... push a new object to the array and use the
  // array length as the id
  res.push({ name: input.value, id: res.length + 1 });

  // Reset the input value
  input.value = '';
  console.log(res);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input"/>
<button id="btn">Save</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
    let res = [];
    const input = (document.getElementById("input").onchange = function(e) {
      const btn = (document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
        const user = {
          name: e.target.value,
          id: 1
        };
        res.push(user);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res));

      });
    });
```

```html
    name<input type='text' id='input'/>
    <button id="btn">save</button>
```

Object.assign({}) doesn't concatenate instead it merges the object properties by replacing. To create objects by concatenating one of the possible ways is to push them into an array. Hope this helps!